# Firestore getting most liked posts

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a simple app in which I want to introduce most liked posts. I'm using `Cloud Firestore`. My question is how the query should look like in this case? (I'm using Java)

Here's the `Firestore` tree:

```
-ROOT
--Posts
---Post
----Likes
```

Likes collection is set of users' ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `Likes` property is of type number and not String, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference ref = rootRef.collection("Posts").document("Post");
ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                long numberOfLikes = document.getLong("Likes");
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(numberOfLikes));
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The output in your logcat will be the number of likes.